# Ruby, GTK3. Getting the icon by mime type

Tags: ruby, mime-types, gtk3, gio

I'm trying to get icon associated with a mime-type in Ruby using Gio::ContentType.get_icon, but it fails with error:

```
main.rb:11:in `get_icon': no implicit conversion of Module into String (TypeError)
from main.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "gtk3"
require "glib2"
require "gio2"


mime_type = "image/jpeg"
icon = Gio::ContentType.get_icon(mime_type)
```

I really don't understand why this happens or what i'm doing wrong...

Any help would be appreciated. And sorry for bad english.

Comment: That was a bug http://sourceforge.net/p/ruby-gnome2/bugs/186/. Solved.